# main.CRITICAL: Email template '' is not defined. at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php:225)"} []]

Tags: magento2, email-templates, exception, debugging

in my exception.log i see this error message, I am unable to trace where the exception came from.

magento: 2.2.6

```
main.CRITICAL: Email template '' is not defined. {"exception":"[object] (UnexpectedValueException(code: 0): Email template '' is not defined. at /public_html/vendor/magento/module-email/Model/Template/Config.php:225)"} []
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found the issue.
It was due to one of the custom email template (New Customer Confirmation) migrated from magento 1 that was not generating contents properly. fix the email template from the admin panel (marketing->email templates) resolved the issue.

Comment: Just set the default template and it is working fine.